# Is there a place where I can buy new stock GM Engines?

Tags: engine, replace

I am looking into a new project, and one idea that was tossed around is to replace the motor on the truck with a FlexFuel model. I looked around and see [gmperformanceparts website](http://www.gmperformanceparts.com), but they don't have stock engines. I also saw [this site](http://www.newgmengines.com/) which is almost dead on, except the newest block they list is an '07, I'm looking for something newer.

Yes, I'm aware this would require more work than just dropping the motor in, but remember this is a *project*, so little problems along the way won't detract from the overall goal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can by an engine from the dealer. Call around the price can very dramatically from dealer to dealer. Some of the high volume (parts sales) dealers will sell over the counter for less than a normal dealer would pay for the engine from GM. One of the dealers in my area sells hundreds if not thousands of engines a year. It was cheaper for my dealer to buy it from them that to purchase from GM.

Salvage yards my be your best bet, because you will get a more complete engine and the other components you will need to make the switch. The flex fuel vehicles have more changes that just the engine, they use different fuel delivery components as well. The high ethanol content will destroy standard fuel line for example.

Not sure what you're motivation is for switching, if it's for money or fuel savings make sure you really explore the differences and the costs before switching. If you're doing it because you think it's cool and you're not as concerned with the money savings then drive on.

Comment: Sounds good, I knew I could probably get the fuel system components from a parts dealer, just needed clarification that the dealer and/or the parts sellers would have access to the whole block. Is it that common for a salvage yard to have these newer model cars? I suppose if the car has been totaled by the ins company, but the block is in good shape then that's a good deal.